# Use apply function on subsequently more columns

Tags: r, apply

I am a new user of R, I am using an apply function to count the similar variables in columns. I want to first count the similar variables in the first column, but then instead of just counting the similar variables in the second column I want to count the first and second columns. And then subsequently adding an additional column.
 `apply(df, 2, function(x){ x1 <- count(na.omit(x))})`

My data looks like this.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c('a', 'b', 'b'), y = c(NA, 'b','c'), z = c(NA, NA, 'a'))
```

I want this output :

```
|x|count|
a | 1
b | 2

|x|y|count|
b | b | 1
b | c | 1

|x|y|z|count
b | c |a | 1
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Why the repost of your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032607/looping-a-function-in-r), which you clearly decided to take down, instead of responding to the comments various people had left? That's not how things work around here!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a re-post of an [identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032607/looping-a-function-in-r) by OP; instead of responding to comments, OP decided to delete and repost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can consider using the `dplyr` package to achieve this task.

```
library(dplyr)

lapply(1:ncol(df), function(i){
  df2 <- df %>%
    select(1:i) %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    group_by_all() %>%
    tally() %>%
    ungroup()
  return(df2)
})

# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   x         n
#   <fct> <int>
# 1 a         1
# 2 b         2
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   x     y         n
#   <fct> <fct> <int>
# 1 b     b         1
# 2 b     c         1
# 
# [[3]]
# # A tibble: 1 x 4
#   x     y     z         n
#   <fct> <fct> <fct> <int>
# 1 b     c     a         1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexing to access the columns and then `table` to get a Frequency table as follows:

```
lapply(seq_len(ncol(df)), 
    function(i) {
        #take only complete cases, i.e. discard those rows with any NAs in columns
        x <- df[complete.cases(df[, seq_len(i)]), seq_len(i)]

        #use table to get frequency count
        as.data.frame(table(x))
})
```

output:

```
[[1]]
  x Freq
1 a    1
2 b    2

[[2]]
  x y Freq
1 b b    1
2 b c    1

[[3]]
  x y z Freq
1 b c a    1
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. When I use your code I get a different output. I see, is there any way to exclude 0 freqs? 
x y freq 
a b 0
bc   1
ac   0
bc  1

Comment: i excluded 0 freqs using `complete.cases`. otherwise you can use `out[out$Freq > 0,]` where out is the output from `as.data.frame(table(df))`